# Майкл и астероиды

Tags: java, c++, алгоритм, pascal

Вобщем, условие задачи:

> Майкл хочет провести свой космический корабль через опасное астероидное поле в форме решетки N*N (1 <= N <= 500). Решетка содержит K астероидов (1 <= K <= 10,000), которые расположены в узлах решетки.
>
> У Майкла есть мощное оружие, которое способно уничтожить все астероиды в заданной строке или заданном столбце одним выстрелом. Это оружие очень дорогое, и поэтому Майкл хочет использовать его экономно. По заданному расположению астероидов на поле, найдите минимальное количество выстрелов, которое требуется сделать Майклу, чтобы уничтожить все астероиды.
>
> Формат ввода:
>
> - Строка 1: Два целых числа N и K, разделенных одним пробелом
> - Строки 2..K+1: Каждая строка содержит два разделенных пробелом числа R и C (1 <= R, C <= N), обозначающие соответственно координаты строки и колонки астероида.
>
> Пример ввода:
>
> 3 4
> 1 1
> 1 3
> 2 2
> 3 2
>
> Детали ввода:
>
> Следующая диаграмма представляет заданную решетку, где 'X' обозначает астероид, а '.' обозначает отсутствие астероида.
>
> X.X
> .X.
> .X.
>
> Формат вывода:
>
> - Строка 1: Целое число, представляющее минимальное количество выстрелов, которые должен сделать Майкл
>
> Пример вывода:
>
> 2
>
> Детали вывода:
>
> Майкл может выстрелить по строке 1, уничтожив астероиды в позициях (1,1) и (1,3), а затем выстрелить по колонке 2, уничтожив астероиды в позициях (2,2) и (3,2).
>
> Ограничение по памяти: 32 Мб. Ограничение по времени: 1 секунда.

Comment: хорошая задачка) завтра попробую решить))

Comment: завтра - растяжимое понятие... =)

Comment: Вы бы сразу указали сайт с этой задачкой, где можно запостить своё решение, наверняка такая возможность там есть, что бы проверить свой код. К примеру у меня есть идея как это решить, но я сомневаюсь что оно подойдёт для всех вариантов

Comment: Может и есть сайт, где можно это протестировать, но мне в универе дают только тесты и условия, так что тестирую я в своей системе (локальной копии моего сайта)...

Answer (score 2):

Сформируем двудольный граф с N вершинами в каждой доле. Вершины одной из долей будут соответствовать столбцам, вершины другой доли - строкам. Для каждого астероида добавим ребро между вершинами, соответствующими столбцу и строке астероида. Теперь заметим, что ответом к задаче является размер [минимального вершинного покрытия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8) в этом графе. По [теореме Кёнига](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) размер минимального вершинного покрытия в двудольном графе равен размеру максимального паросочетания. А максимальное паросочетание в двудольном графе можно найти, например, [алгоритмом Куна](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/kuhn_matching) за время порядка O(NK).

Comment: Ваше решение не успеет отработать за секунду.

Comment: Виноват, написал грубую оценку времени (для полного графа). Более точная оценка - O(NK). Так как у вас граф достаточно разрежённый (K <= 10000), то в результате операций будет всего 5 млн.

Comment: Вообще-то, N^3 = 125 млн тоже успеет за секунду на большинстве олимпиадных серверов.

Comment: @quyse
Что-то я на счёт 125 млн очень сильно сомневаюсь... Напишите решение, а то так на счёт правильности и эффективность ооочень долго спорить будем.

Comment: Да сомневайтесь, сколько вашей душе угодно :) Решение я писать вам не буду.